# Expression as a limit in HTML input type number

Tags: html, expression

How can I pass an expression as a max or min or step value in HTML input type number element. For example I want something like

```
<input type="number" name="userChunkSize" min="500*1024" max="50*1024*1024" step="100*1024" value="1*1024*1024">
```

The example given above isn't working as It lets the value to be incremented by 1

I was expecting something like

```
min=eval(500*1024)
```

may be able to help but this also doesn't seem to work with different combinations of "

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know if i understand your question but might as well give it a go.

If you have the possibility for javascript :

```
<script>
    var min = 500*1024;
    var max = 50*1024*1024;
    var step = 100*1024;
    var value = 1*1024*1024;
    document.getElementById("yourdiv").innerHTML = "<input type='number' name='userChunkSize' min='"+min+"' max='"+max+"' step='"+step+"' value='"+value+"'>"
</script>
<body>
 <div id="yourdiv"></div> 
</body>
```

but i dont really see why you want to do this, since the values will still always be the same, you might as well calculate it yourself and directly define it in html

Comment: Thanks @Koen for the response. I want to put it as expression so it is more human readable. 50*1024*1024 is easy to understand as 50 MB but the actual value of the expression   31457280 is really not that intuitive.

Comment: ooh, i doubt that it's possible and if it's possible i have no clue how to do that, sorry :(

Comment: Any suggestions on how would you have liked to improve the readability

Comment: Why dont you just use MB as the standard measurement? so that you can just use steps of 1 or 0.1 and display the value as MB's?

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I edited the question with more details if it helps